# Ordinary differential equation­

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}-\dfrac{\tan y}{1+x}=(1+x)e^x\sin y$$

I tried $\sin y=t$ but failed. It seems to immune to methods I know of or I am just unable to make the right substitution... Wolfram alpha responds with standard computation time exceeded. Any hints or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: So nonlinear...you have reasons to think it has a closed form solution?

Comment: @TylerHG It was in my college exam... 2 marks...

Comment: My god. If the professor ever gives you the solution definitely post it! @Awesome

Comment: Here's the link if anyone doubts...  http://10.17.32.9/peqp/2010/mid%20autumn%202010/Mathematics/mathematics%201.pdf

Comment: That link is dead.  That IP address makes it seem like the link is local to a particular server @Awesome

Comment: have you tried multiplying by $\sec^2(y)$ and then using $\frac{d}{dx}tan(y) = \sec^2(y)y'$. Then manipulating from there? I tried that and got to $$
\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{1+v^2} - \frac{\sqrt{1+v^2}}{1+x} = (1+x)\mathrm{e}^x
$$ after subbing in $v=\tan(y)$ but I feel it is just cleaning up the equation rather than a method to a solution!!

Comment: I transformed the equation into $$
\frac{{dx}}{{dy}} = \frac{{\left( {1 + x} \right)\cot y}}{{\left( {1 + x} \right)^2 e^x \cos y + 1}}
$$ This is not exact, we need to find an integrating factor!